# Make a For Loop more Efficient

Tags: r

I have two dataframes for men and women working in a company. One is 15000 rows x 1000 columns and the other is 150 x 1000. Each column represents an attribute (e.g, Salary, Height, etc...). I am comparing female and male employees within each Bracket (there are five in total).

Below I created some dummy data and the for loop.

```
#Create the data
num_of_employee = 100
f <- rep(c("Female"), 15)
m <- rep(c("Male"), 85)

Employee = paste("Employee",seq(1:num_of_employee))
Bracket = sample(seq(1,5,1),num_of_employee, replace = TRUE)
Height = sample(seq(65,100, 1),num_of_employee, replace = TRUE)
Weight = sample(seq(120,220, 1),num_of_employee, replace = TRUE)
Years_Employed = sample(seq(1,13, 1),num_of_employee, replace = TRUE)
Income = sample(seq(50000,200000, 1000),num_of_employee, replace = TRUE)
gender <- sample(append(f,m), replace = FALSE)
df1 = data.frame(Employee, Height, Weight, Years_Employed, Income, Bracket, gender)

women <-df1[df1$gender == 'Female',]
men <- df1[df1$gender == 'Male',]
```

So that's all the data. Now, this for-loop essentially compares both the men and women dataframes column by column. So for example, Income from df1 will be compared to Income from df2, likewise for Height, Years_Employed etc...

```
v <-c()
runs <- 1000
for(j in 1:runs){
male_vector <- c()
female_vector <- c()

#loop through each of the 5 Brackets
for(z in 1:5){

#print out number of rows in each bracket. 
number_of_rows <- length(which(women$Bracket == z))

#compare attributes of men and women within each bracket.
male_vector <- append(male_vector, men[sample(which(men$Bracket == z), number_of_rows), ]$Height)
female_vector <- append(female_vector, women[which(women$Bracket == z), ]$Height)


 }
 #Ask, are men and women different?
  v <- append(v, sum(male_vector) > sum(female_vector))


}
#How many times are the men>women out of 1000?
as.numeric(sum(v))
[1] 70
```

So this code works, but I want to compare **each column** - meaning `Height`, `Weight`, `Years_Employed` and `Income`.

## Edit

I would like to input the two dataframes and the output be the following:

```
"Height " 0.223
"Salary: " 0.994
"Weight: " 0.006
"Years_Employed:"  0.325
.
.
.
"1000th column :" 0.013
```

Note, my actual data consists of 1000 columns, so hard-coding anything (the way I originally did it), won't work.

Comment: `Status` is not defined, the creation of `df1` throws an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is much simpler than your code.
Note that there are loops in disguise, namely `split` and `sapply`. But the code is cleaner and it avoids repeating the same computations over and over again.

If you call `set.seed(4358)` just before running your code the result will be exactly the same as the result of `mean(v)` in the end of this.

```
set.seed(4358)    # Needed because of the call to sample()

runs <- 1000

v <- logical(runs)
df1_br <- split(df1, df1$Bracket)
df2_br <- split(df2, df2$Bracket)
female_vector <- sapply(df2_br, function(x) sum(x$Income))
sum_female_vector <- sum(female_vector)
number_of_rows <- sapply(df2_br, nrow)

for(j in 1:runs){
  male_vector <- sapply(seq_along(df1_br), function(i) sum(sample(df1_br[[i]]$Income, number_of_rows[i], TRUE)))
  v[j] <- sum(male_vector) > sum_female_vector
}

mean(v)
#[1] 0.933
```

**Sample data.**

I have recreated the datasets by first calling `set.seed()`.

```
set.seed(6736)

num_of_employee = 15000

#Create their attributes
Employee <- paste("Employee", 1:num_of_employee)
Bracket <- sample(1:5, num_of_employee, replace = TRUE)
Height <- sample(65:100, num_of_employee, replace = TRUE)
Weight <- sample(120:220, num_of_employee, replace = TRUE)
Years_Employed <- sample(1:13, num_of_employee, replace = TRUE)
Income <- sample(seq(50000, 200000, 1000), num_of_employee, replace = TRUE)
gender <- sample(c("Female", "Male"), num_of_employee, prob = c(150, 14850)/15000, replace = TRUE)

#Finally make a dataframe for all their data
df1 = data.frame(Employee, Height, Weight, Years_Employed, Income, Bracket, gender)
#Split the dataframe by gender
df2 <- df1[df1$gender == 'Female', ]
df1 <- df1[df1$gender == 'Male', ]
```

**Edit.**

To have the code above accept any column, rewrite it as a function.

```
compareGender <- function(Female, Male, what = "Income", Runs = 1000){

  v <- logical(Runs)
  Male_br <- split(Male, Male[["Bracket"]])
  Female_br <- split(Female, Female[["Bracket"]])
  female_vector <- sapply(Female_br, function(x) sum(x[[what]]))
  sum_female_vector <- sum(female_vector)
  number_of_rows <- sapply(Female_br, nrow)

  for(j in seq_len(Runs)){
    male_vector <- sapply(seq_along(Male_br), function(i) sum(sample(Male_br[[i]][[what]], number_of_rows[i], TRUE)))
    v[j] <- sum(male_vector) > sum_female_vector
  }

  c(what = mean(v))
}

set.seed(4358)    # To compare the result with the result above
compareGender(Female = df2, Male = df1)
#[1] 0.933


compareGender(Female = df2, Male = df1, what = "Height")
#[1] 0.012

compareGender(Female = df2, Male = df1, what = "Years_Employed")
#[1] 0.815
```

If you want to apply the function to several columns automatically, you can use the `*apply` functions.
In this case I will `sapply` the function to columns 2 to 5, or to `names(df1)[2:5]`.

```
res <- sapply(names(df1)[2:5], function(x) compareGender(df2, df1, x))
names(res) <- sub("\\.what$", "", names(res))

res
#Height         Weight Years_Employed         Income 
#0.012          0.211          0.827          0.948
```

Now, you can transform this output into a data.frame. There are two ways you can do it. The first creates a df with one column and the `names` attribute as the row names. The second creates a df with two columns, the original column names and the mean values returned by `compareGender`.

```
final1 <- data.frame(Mean = res)
final1
#                Mean
#Height         0.012
#Weight         0.211
#Years_Employed 0.827
#Income         0.948


final2 <- data.frame(Variable = names(res), Mean = res)
row.names(final2) <- NULL
final2
#        Variable  Mean
#1         Height 0.012
#2         Weight 0.211
#3 Years_Employed 0.827
#4         Income 0.948
```

Comment: My issue is with ```$Income```. This is comparing the incomes of men and women. i want to compare every column automatically (meaning income, height, years employed etc...).

Comment: This is my fault, I didn't articulate my desired output enough. My actual dataframe is 15000 rows x 1000 columns. Is there a way to automate it so it runs for 1000 columns? I upvoted your answer nonetheless.

Comment: @Workhorse I have edited the answer showing a way to do what you want. Note that **the function has changed**.

Comment: Sorry it took me a while to answer, was trying hard to understand what the function was doing. Really nice, I learned a lot from you. Thank you.